# how to override functions like QTreeWidget::currentItem() when using a subclass inherit from QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to put some extrenal data in QTreeWidgetItem, so I made a subclass like this.

```
class DContentItem :public QTreeWidgetItem
{
public:
    DContentItem();
    const QString randomName = generateRandomName();
private:
    QString generateRandomName();
};
```

then I add one to a QTreeWidget:

```
DContentItem *item = new DContentItem();
item->setText(0, "New One");
ui->widgetTree->addTopLevelItem(item);
```

when someone click the tree, I want to access it.

```
DContentItem *current_item = ui->widgetTree->currentItem();
```

But this gives an error, from currtItem（）return QTreeWidgetItem, but here what I want is a DContentItem.

> error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'DContentItem *' with an rvalue of type 'QTreeWidgetItem *'

I have tried writing a new function to return a DConteItem, but it seems a little complex. What is the better way to do this?

class a
class b subclass a
function foo return a
how to let it return b?

Comment: You should cast `QTreeWidgetItem` pointer to `DContentItem` using `dynamic_cast`. I would even use `static_cast` if it's guaranteed that all tree widget items are of type `DContentItem`. From the other hand, sub classing here seems to be an overkill. You might consider using `QTreeWidgetItem::setData()` function to store extra data in a standard tree widget items.

Comment: Yes they are all DContentItem. I will google for static_cast. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I may add something new to it, so I choose to ues subclass. Thanks to you again.Now I use `DContentItem *current_item = static_cast<DContentItem *>(ui->widgetTree->currentItem());` and it works. However is it necessary to use `ui->widgetTree->addTopLevelItem(static_cast<QTreeWidgetItem *>(item));` too?

Comment: No, because `DContentItem` **is** a `QTreeWidgetItem`. The opposite is not true, though.

Comment: I got it. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Wrong:

```
 DContentItem *current_item = ui->widgetTree->currentItem();
```

Correct:

```
 DContentItem *current_item = static_cast<DContentItem *>(ui->widgetTree->currentItem());
```

Thanks [vahancho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2674506/vahancho) very much.